# Server side synch up code for mobile applications

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, blackberry

We are planning on developing a cloud service where any mobile application that requires to synchronize data into a server is available out-of-box on a public hosting. This will be done using a NoSQL database and hence any data can be saved easily and only requires a HTTP/JSON communication.

Are there any out-of-box solutions already available in this space which majority of the mobile developers use?

We want to get your opinion on whether this is something that can help mobile developers?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS there is something called [RestKit](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Frestkit.org%2F&ei=_7hyUfHjGMX5rAfj0oC4Ag&usg=AFQjCNEZpFyLIv9sJOPi6Zu3m7z9hndu_w&sig2=CLi62yPyNcGZV75uhRhvvA&bvm=bv.45512109,d.bmk) that automatically gets response, parses it and gives you a dynamic object. It works with all kinds of servers and response types. Hope this helps a bit, for server side configuration you can use [Apigee](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CD0QjBAwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapigee.com%2Fabout%2Fpressrelease%2Fapigee-study-mobile-app-dependency-high-varies-country&ei=pLpyUbDQDsb4rQfa8YG4AQ&usg=AFQjCNEkeMC2BccF48MlOXN42pKuxM2z5w&sig2=KY5D13K2aJaf2hGs0NVgjA&bvm=bv.45512109,d.bmk) which does something similar. I have worked on both so thought it would be useful for you.